# Passing a SharePoint Site Workflow Variable Value to List Item Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow

I have created a SharePoint Site Workflow to capture the Today date. The value will be stored in a SharePoint workflow variable (a local variable). Please refer the below screenshot.

[image]

Then I have tried to add that value to the SharePoint column 'Today Date' in the SharePoint List 'EMEA Documents'using the below step in the workflow.

[image]

The whole workflow is as the below.

[image]

This will try to pass the today date for every 30 minutes, captured from the workflow variable to the column 'Today Date' in 'EMEA Documents' SharePoint list.

Is this possible with this solution?

Please help me to solve this.

---

I updated the step 'Update List Item'. Please refer the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Question: Adding a repetitive WOrkflow to list items will create hundreds or more running instants of the workflow, This may cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a Site Workflow?

In the step below, you will not find any item from EMEA Documents because the “Today Date” is not equal to the current date.

[image]

You can use a list workflow instead, update Current Item.

[image]

In addition: You can create a column named “Today” to make the SharePoint to use [Today] (current date) as part of formula. After using Today in calculated column, delete the “Today” column to make SharePoint get the default [Today] current date. If you need to edit formula, you need create “Today” column again, then edit formula.

For more details, you can refer the following article. This article is for SharePoint 2010, buy it still applies to SharePoint 2013.

https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/

**Update:**

Based on your requirement, you need a list workflow instead of a site workflow. 
A list workflow runs on a single item in the list/library. Use "Find the list item" filter in "Update List Item" action will only return one result from the data source if there are multiple results. So, using a list workflow on all items in the list is better.

Otherwise, you can iterate items in the list with filter in the site workflow, refer to https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: I tried to use the Site workflow to update the Today Date column of the EMEA Document List every 24 hour and for every list item. This should be in a loop.

Other thing is I will do a date difference calculation in a different column to store the value. The formula will look like [Date Difference] = [Today Date] - [Expiration Date]. Date Difference reached 30 & 10 2 email alerts should trigger.

Comment: Please refer the updated question.

Comment: Based on your requirement, you need a list workflow instead of a site workflow. A list workflow runs on a single item in the list/library. Use "Find the list item" filter in "Update List Item" action will only return one result from the data source if there are multiple results. So, using a list workflow on all items in the list is better. Otherwise, you can iterate items in the list with filter in the site workflow, refer to https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: By the way, why do you need Today? If you want to get Today in the column, you can check my steps in the answer, using calculated column to get Today.

Comment: Why I need Today date in the column, because I want to trigger a workflow checking a column called 'Expiration date' and do a calculation like [Date difference] = [Today] - [Expiration Date]. If the Date difference is 30 an email alert will be triggered and also if the Date difference is 10 an email alert will be triggered. But once an item is submitted the Today Date will be the date when the item is submitted and it won't be changed in every 24 hour. To change it I have managed to develop a simple site workflow to grab the Today Date and pass it to a workflow variable.

Comment: But I cannot push the workflow variable value to the Today Date column in the SharePoint list. This value needs to be inserted to all the list items. Once done that I can do the calculation every 24 hour to find out the Date Difference.